# c# regexp match

Tags: c#, regex

I have the regexp:

```
\[IN\](\d+)\[/IN\]
```

Which works fine for:

```
...[IN]34[/IN]...
...[IN]1[/IN]...
...[IN]12[/IN]...
etc
```

But it doesn't quite work for decimals, IE:

> ```
> ...[IN]3.5[/IN]...
> ...[IN]2.8[/IN]...
> ...[IN]9.4[/IN]...
> etc
> ```

How do I make it match these as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Can there also be exponents (`1.4E-3`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the top of my head i think it should be this:

```
[IN](\d+\.?\d*)[/IN]
```

EDIT: tested and corrected version:

```
\[IN\](\d+(\.\d+)?)\[\/IN\]
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't check if it is valid float (have one decimal dot):

```
([\d.]+)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
\[IN\]\d+(\.\d+)?\[/IN\]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
[IN](\d+|\d+\.\d+)?[/IN]
```

This ensures that you have a number after the dot if you have a dot.